# Hacking a Bluetooth headset

Tags: networking, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-3.0

So I have a Samsung HM1300 (http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/BHM1300NBACSTA).

I would like to hack this device, and transmit the button data from the call button for something else. Is this possible? I am just starting to learn about bluetooth, and I am not sure what is possible/not possible.

To be more clear, the device currently has volume up/down buttons and also a talk/accept call button. I would like to pair the device with my computer, and have some script running that receives all the bluetooth commands that are sent over. If someone presses the call button, the script should receive that data and do some action.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on the Arduino site for this. Actually, there are a few depending on whether you have the [BT board](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardBT?from=Main.ArduinoBoardBluetooth). If you don't have the board then you'll need a BT modem for this. Here is the tutorial: http://playground.arduino.cc/learning/tutorial01

Comment: I don't think this'll work for me. I am trying to connect my Samsung HM1300 Headset to my computer/android device and read the button presses. I don't understand how the tutorial helps with this task. Maybe some clarification please?